# Postgresql : Filtering duplicate pair

Tags: postgresql

I am asking this from mobile, so apologies for bad formatting. For the following table.

Table players

```
| ID | name |matches_won|
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
| 1  | bob  | 3         |
| 2  | Paul | 2         |
| 3  | John | 4         |
| 4  | Jim  | 1         |
| 5  | hal  | 0         |
| 6  | fin  | 0         |
```

I want to pair two players together in a query. Who have a similar or near similar the number of matches won. So the query should display the following result.

```
| ID | NAME | ID | NAME |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
| 3  | John |  1 | bob  |
| 2  | paul |  4 | Jim  |
| 5  | hal  |  6 | fin  |
```

Until now I have tried this query. But it gives repeat pairs.

```
Select player1.ID,player1.name,player2.ID,player2.name
From player as player1,
          player as player2
Where 
player1.matches_won >= player2.matches_won
And player1.ID  ! = player2.ID;
```

The query will pair the player with the most won matches with everyone of the other players. While I only want one player to appear only once in the result. With the player who is nearest to his wins.

I have tried sub queries. But I don't know how to go about it, since it only returns one result. Also aggregates don't work in the where clause. So I am not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way, IMHO, to achieve this would be to order the players by their number of wins, divide these ranks by two to create matches and self join. CTEs (`with` expressions) allow you to do this relatively elegantly:

```
WITH wins AS (
    SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMNBER() OVER (ORDER BY matches_won DESC) AS rn   
    FROM players
)
SELECT     w1.id, w1.name, w2.id, w2.name
FROM       (SELECT id, name, rn / 2 AS rn
            FROM   wins
            WHERE  rn % 2 = 1) w1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, name, (rn - 1) / 2 AS rn
           FROM   wins
           WHERE  rn % 2 = 0) w2 ON w1.rn = w2.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Add row numbers in descending order by won matches to the table and join odd row numbers with adjacent even row numbers:

```
with players as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by matches_won desc) rn
    from player)

select a.id, a.name, b.id, b.name
from players a
join players b
on a.rn = b.rn- 1
where a.rn % 2 = 1

 id | name | id | name 
----+------+----+------
  3 | John |  1 | bob
  2 | Paul |  4 | Jim
  5 | hal  |  6 | fin
(3 rows)
```